# Can $x^{n}-1$ be prime if $x$ is not a power of $2$ and $n$ is odd?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, exponentiation

Are there any solutions to $x^{n}-1=p$ with p prime, integers $x,n>1$ and $x$ not a power of $2$?

$x$ must be even. $n$ is odd since if $n=2m$ then $p=x^{n}-1=(x^{m}+1)(x^{m}-1)$ hence $p=x^{m}+1$ and $1=x^{m}-1$, which has solution $p=3$ given by $x=2^{2}$.

This generalises; for any solution to $x^{n}-c^{2}=p$, $n$ must be odd. And for any solution to $x^{n}-c=p$, $x$ is odd iff $c$ is odd unless $p=2$ and, if $a$ divides $c$ and $p$ does not divide $c$ then $x$ divides $c$.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following result can be found in most introductions to Number Theory.

**Theorem**: Let $x$ and $n$ be integers greater than $1$.  If $x^n-1$ is prime, then $x=2$ and $n$ is prime.

**Proof**: Note that $x-1$ divides $x^n-1$, for
$$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+ \cdots + 1).$$
If $x>2$ and $n>1$, each of the above factors of $x^n-1$ is $>1$. It follows that if $x>2$ and $n>1$, then $x^n-1$ cannot be prime. So if $x^n-1$ is prime, then $x=2$.

Next we show that if $2^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ itself must be prime. For suppose to the contrary that $n=ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are greater than $1$. Then 
$$2^n-1=2^{ab}-1=(2^a)^b-1.$$
Let $y=2^a$. Then $2^n-1=y^b-1$. But $y-1$ divides $y^b-1$. Thus 
$2^a-1$ divides $2^n-1$. It is easy to see that in fact $2^a-1$ is a *proper* divisor of $2^n-1$, so $2^n-1$ cannot be prime.

This concludes the proof.  By calculating, we can verify that $2^n-1$ is prime for $n=2$, $3$, $5$, and $7$. But one should not jump to conclusions. When $n=11$, $2^n-1$ is not prime, for $23$ divides $2^{11}$.

Primes of the form $2^n-1$ (where $n$ is necessarily prime) are called [Mersenne primes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime)

There has been interest in what would later be called Mersenne primes ever since the time of Euclid, because of their connection with the even [perfect numbers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)  Despite a search spanning millenia, only $47$ Mersenne primes are currently known.   The current record holder is $2^{43,112,609}-1$. From the computational evidence, it appears that for "most" primes $p$, the number $2^p-1$ is not prime. It is not known whether there are infinitely many Mersenne primes.

Comment: Is there a proof that if $X>2$ then $X^n-1$ cannot be prime?

Comment: @michaelmross:  Sure, for $n\gt 1$. We have  $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots +1)$, and each factor on the right is $\ge 2$.